# How to make tip position absolute for foundation joyride?

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

One of my joyride tips is attached to a link on the navigation header (which has absolute positioning).

How can I add custom styling to that particular joyride tip to make it have absolute positioning as well? The joyride docs indicate that I can create custom styles for the default classes but the default classes aren't specific to each particular joyride tip.

Answer (score 0):

In Step 3 of their documentation, they show an example of how to add your own custom class to each tip: http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin

```
<li data-id="parentElementID" class="custom-class">Content...</li>
<li data-class="parentElementClass" class="custom-class">Content...</li>
```

This will generated out something like this.

```
<div class="joyride-tip-guide custom-class" data-index="0">...</div>
```